# Is it possible to measure the distance of a WiFi access point from the receiver?

Tags: wireless, wifi, wifi-direct

I have signal strength in dBm and frequency in MHz.  Is it possible to find the distance?

Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: It helps if the transmitter tells you what its effective power level measured at a reference distance is, but the results will still be of limited reliability, see for example "iBeacon" RSSI-based distancing on 2.4 GHz BLE.

Comment: No reason to close this - it's a technique in actual use, with known issues, and the question asks if it is possible, not for a how-to on implementing it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I totally agree with you, moreover a question like this can produce pretty nice and informative answers from great guys around here.

Answer (score 5):

There are several research papers claiming that there is no correlation between signal strength and distance. I've read it - among others - on [*Radio Link Quality Estimation in Wireless Sensor Networks: a Survey*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sics.se%2F~luca%2Fpapers%2Fbaccour11link.pdf&ei=-fLMU5DUKIas0QWDiIHwBw&usg=AFQjCNHl5HZeKvZZIFxNV-InMVkFuw2A_A&sig2=Bc4qyhf1rnB4uNpbThWghw&bvm=bv.71198958,d.d2k) by Baccour.

Now, I don't think this is true - there *must* be a correlation, otherwise you could *in principle* receive wifi signals from across the world. But it is demonstrated that this dependency is overwhelmed by other factors, such as the non-uniform radiation pattern of the antenna, multi-path propagation (highly significant due to the short wavelength), scattering and path loss due to obstacles.

Comment: Quite true, I've looked at this for an application at work (a sort of indoor GPS)... and it is very difficult to get accurate results. Your chances are increased with the more access points you have at your disposal for more accurate triangulation... In the end, I just went with a more basic approach. At least in my application, the user would check in multiple times in between an activity, and thus easier to just use extrapolation for their location.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say in my opinion, long answer yes (with some work) short answer no. The way I see it would be either through signal strength or the amount of time it took to get the signal.
Correct me if I am wrong on any of this...

Theoretically we could send a time stamp along with the signal that could tell us the exact time that the signal left the sending device. The receiving device could then figure out how long the signal took to get there by comparing it with the current time. with radio waves propagating at the speed of light (186,000 miles per second), it would only take 5.376 micro-seconds to travel 1 mile.
that means if you had something like an ESP32 wi-fi chip with a processor running at 240MHz (which is 1 cycle every 4.167 nano-seconds), the CPU would do 1290 cycles for each mile the signal has traveled. That means the signal would have traveled 4.1 feet for each cycle of the CPU.
I'm not sure how many cycles it takes for the CPU to get the time, load it into a variable and then send that information over the Wi-Fi, but if were 10 cycles you could be off be 40ft. Though this could be factored out of the time if you knew exactly how many cycles it took and if it took the same number of cycles each time. You then might be able to figure out exact distance and with a few Wi-Fi points you could even triangulate a position. We know this approach works because that is how GPS is able to figure our your location on your phone. The trouble is they tend to not work as well indoors. GPS runs somewhere between 1.2GHz and 1.6GHz so a 2.4GHz WiFi would most likely have more trouble indoors.

This method would require exact clock synchronizations to work though (GPS satellites use atomic clocks)

you could try to ping the source and measure the response time, but there would be a lot of time variables to consider and with almost 1 million feet covered every second. 1ms extra response time would give you an error of almost 200 miles.

Lastly by strength might work great with line of site, and multiple measurements. This method would break down quickly once walls or even bad weather like rain or snow are introduced.

In the end it would probably be easier to just get a gps for each WiFi involved.

I myself had been asking this same question while trying to set up a mesh network using esp32 chips. Since I wanted the network to be fluid and establish new pathways on the fly, a signal could be sent down all possible paths to get a total latency with the home base for each path. But to make sure that a signal doesn't get stuck in a "loop" in an area with lots of nodes, the signal should always be propagating closer to the home base (with some exceptions). The solution was to assign each node a name based on distance from the home base which could be measured out or estimated in some cases (google Earth works great for estimating larger distances).

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

All other things being equal (and that is a lot to ask!) there is indeed a relation between transmitter signal strength, distance, frequency, and receiver signal strength.

Are you trying to determine your location from WiFi signal strength? There is lots of info about this on the web.

Comment: Yes, off course. Can you please suggest me some links???

Comment: google for instance "wifi positioning" or "wifi location". It deoes require calibrating: walking around, measuring, and noting down your position.  IIRC there is even some open source software for this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a correlation between signal strength and distance! As you can see from this discussion over on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24253/geometry-of-wireless-signal-strength) there is no fixed equation to tell you distance from signal strength, as you don't know output power, antenna length/ field pattern/geometry, propagation paths, etc, and in fact even things like the weather can change how well the signal propagates.

So what tools like [kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/) do (extensively used in wifi site surveys and security tests) is to plot signal strength along with location and use triangulation. Broadly speaking, excluding external factors, two points that have the same signal strength are likely to be equidistant from the wireless access point. Using many samples helps pin down locations pretty accurately.

Comment: I disagree with the last part. It's been found that, because of multi-path propagation, moving the receiver a few centimeters (even sideways) can change the received signal by as much as 10dB. Not to mention the effect that walls have.

Comment: clabacchio - no, it really works well! This is where kismet wins - it takes > 10 or 15 points and can come up with a very good map. Some materials are worse than others (warehouses storing rolls of paper or whisky seem especially bad)

Comment: I have updated the wording to make it more obvious.

Answer (score -2):

There are android apps that can view wifi distance.

Comment: Which app? I doubt this actually works.